# Solr: How to create Facets based on tags

Tags: solr, solrnet, faceted-search, facet

If you have a look at the following to links, camers are faceted by Mega pixels. Where as Flash memory is faceted by Memory Size.

http://www.pricegrabber.com/cameras/digital/p-48/
http://www.pricegrabber.com/computers/flash-memory/p-152/

I guess this is based on tags assigned to each product? Any ideas how to create such facets automatically on runtime?  Or am i thinking in the wrong direction. Any help how different facets are created for different products? Or is it just predefining everything?

P.S. I am using Solr in c# with SolrNet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use dynamic fields and generate the facet from the dynamic fields.